# VueJS change date format

Tags: vue.js

Now VueJS display me date in format `2021-02-24 00:12:42`, but how i can change display only `00:12`? Without year, month, date and seconds?

In `vue` i use:

```
<div class="jhistory" v-for="game in histories" :key="game.game_id">
{{ game.date }}
</div>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      histories: {},
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$root.isLoading = true
    this.getHistory();
  },
  methods: {
    getHistory() {
      this.$root.axios.post('/jackpot/history').then(res => {
        this.histories = res.data;
        this.$root.isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well it's not about vuejs, just check `Date` object in javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and it's methods to get hours and minutes and format your time =)

Comment: @yrbet I'm suspicious of that date format as displayed. @halilcakar is correct that this is a JS Date issue, not Vue, but that's not quite exactly any of the standard formats. You're probably getting sent preformatted string instead of something that's parsing to an actual date. Try `{{ typeof game.date}}` to see if the output is "string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a component method that converts the string into a `Date` object, uses [`Date.prototype.toTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString), and takes only the first 5 characters, which contains only the `hh:mm` portion. Another simpler way is to just extract the substring with [`String.prototype.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), assuming the format never changes.

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    toTime(date) {
      // Option 1
      return new Date(date).toTimeString().substr(0,5)

      // Option 2
      return date.substr(11,5)
    }
  }
}
```

Then use the method in your template:

```html
{{ toTime(game.date) }}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    game: {
      date: '2021-02-24 00:12:42'
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    toTime(date) {
      return new Date(date).toTimeString().substr(0,5)
      // OR
      // return date.substr(11,5)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ toTime(game.date) }}</p>
</div>
```